# Calling function from included batch file with a parameter

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In my main batch file I include another batch file and want to call a function defined in there, code looks like following:

```
@echo off
call define_wait.bat

if "%1"=="WAIT" (
    call :WAIT_AND_PRINT 5
    echo.
)

REM rest...
```

My *define_wait.bat* looks like following:

```
:WAIT_AND_PRINT
set /a time=%1
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %time%) do (
    ping -n 1 -w 1000 1.0.0.0 > null
    echo|set /p=.
)
goto :EOF

:WAIT
set /a time="%1 * 1000"
ping -n 1 -w %time% 1.0.0.0 > null
goto :EOF
```

The problem is that if I define the wait function in another batch file it does not work, calling `call :WAIT_AND_PRINT 5` does not hand on the parameter correctly (Error: **missing operand**)... If I copy my code from my *define_wait.bat* int my main batch file, everything works fine...

How would I make that correctly?

Comment: You can't include *functions* from another file. You can write wrappers, macros or use the `call bug-trick`

Comment: Found a way to do it now with calling the bat file + function name and let the function bat forward it's parameters to it's function... I'll post my solution

Answer (score 5):

Working function bat that forwards it's parameters to it's subfunction:

```
@echo off
call %*
goto :EOF

:WAIT_AND_PRINT
set /a time=%1
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %time%) do (
    ping -n 1 -w 1000 1.0.0.0 > null
    echo|set /p=.
)
goto :EOF

:WAIT
set /a time="%1 * 1000"
ping -n 1 -w %time% 1.0.0.0 > null
goto :EOF
```

In the main bat I now don't include the batch file anymore but call it directly like following:

```
call define_wait.bat :WAIT_AND_PRINT 5
```

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't aware of this until [jeb commented it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176267/calling-function-from-included-batch-file-with-a-parameter#comment59988363_36176267), but here's a quick demonstration of the `call` bug he mentioned, using some utility functions I had lying around.

**functions.bat:**

```js
:length <"string">
rem // sets errorlevel to the string length (not including quotation marks)
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
if "%~1"=="" (endlocal & exit /b 0) else set ret=1
set "tmpstr=%~1"
for %%I in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if not "!tmpstr:~%%I,1!"=="" (
        for %%x in ("!tmpstr:~%%I!") do endlocal & (
            set /a ret += %%I
            set "tmpstr=%%~x"
        )
    ) else endlocal
)
endlocal & exit /b %ret%

:password <return_var>
rem // prompts user for password, masks input, and sets return_var to entered value
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
<NUL set /P "=Password? "
set "psCommand=powershell -noprofile "$p=read-host -AsSecureString;^
$m=[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal];$m::PtrToStringAuto($m::SecureStringToBSTR($p))""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do endlocal & set "%~1=%%p"
goto :EOF
```

**main.bat:**

```js
@echo off & setlocal

rem // demo return value
call :password pass

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo You entered !pass!

rem // demo bubbling up of %ERRORLEVEL%
call :length "!pass!"
echo Password length is %ERRORLEVEL%

endlocal
goto :EOF

rem // ====== FUNCTION DECLARATIONS =======

:length <"string">
:password <return_var>
functions.bat %*
```

Output:

> Password? *********
>   You entered something
>   Password length is 9

[This web page](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) offers an explanation:

> If you execute a second batch file *without* using CALL you may run into some buggy behaviour: if both batch files contain a label with the same name and you have previously used CALL to jump to that label in the first script, you will find execution of the second script starts at the same label. Even if the second label does not exist this will still raise an error *"cannot find the batch label"*. This bug can be avoided by always using CALL.

If you've ever done any coding in C++, it helps to think of the labels in main.bat as function *declarations* in a .h file, while the labels in functions.bat would correspond to function *definitions* in a .cpp file.  Or in .NET, the main.bat labels would be like `DllImport("functions.bat")` so to speak.

Comment: I could not find something with "call bug-trick"... I think my posted solution is more reusable, but your's make the call functions shorter (but you have to define all functions again)

Comment: Yeah, my solution is no more or less effective than yours.  I just thought it was an interesting quirk of `call`.

Comment: You don't need to write for each function the complete wrapper, it's enough to stack them all. List all function names, one per line and then one time the `functions.bat %*`

Comment: I think you forgot a `@goto %1` line at beginning of functions.bat file!

Comment: @Aacini Not needed because of the `call` bug.  We're exploiting the bug.  See the quoted text below "This web page offers an explanation" in my answer.  I had originally begun `functions.bat` with `goto :EOF` but even that is not needed.

Comment: Wow, it works! This is a serious bug! No matter if several lines are executed below the called label in the main file; the execution continue at the label in the functions.bat file anyway!

Comment: @Aacini And we discussed about exactly this bug already ... ;-) [Dostips:Call label from other batch file](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6878#p44586)

Comment: @jeb: You are right, but to be honest, a that time I didn't fathom out what exactly the bug was!

Answer (score 2):

Although there are several ways to call a function that reside in a separate *library file*, all methods require to change the way to call the library functions in the calling program, and/or insert additional code at beginning of the library file in order to identify the called function.

There is an interesting trick that allows to avoid all these details, so both the main and the library files contain the original code, and just 2 lines needs to be added to the main file. The method consist in *switch the context* of the running main Batch file to the library file; after that, all functions in the library file are available to the running code. The way to do that is *renaming* the library file with the same name of the main file. After that, when a `call :function` command is executed, the `:function` label will be search *in the library file*! Of course, the files must be renamed back to the original names before the program ends. Ah! I almost forget the key point of this method: both the initial and final renames must be executed *in a code block* in the main file. A simple example:

**main.bat**

```
@echo off
echo Calling :test and :hello functions in the library.bat file:

rem Switch the context to the library file
(ren "%~NX0" temp.bat  &  ren library.bat "%~NX0"

call :test
echo Back from library.bat :test function

call :hello
echo Back from library.bat :hello function

rem Switch the context back to the main file
ren "%~NX0" library.bat  &  ren temp.bat "%~NX0")

echo Continue in main file
```

**library.bat**

```
:test
echo I am :test function in library.bat file
exit /B

:hello
echo I am :hello function in library.bat file
exit /B
```

A drawback of this method is that if a run-time error happens when the files are renamed, the files remains renamed, but this may be fixed in a very simple way. For example, a check.bat file may check if the library.bat file exists, and do the rename back if it was not found.